# Why does my bitmap on the canvas appear below the background drawable?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` where I'm setting a background color and an image like so:

```
BitmapDrawable tiledBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background));
tiledBackground.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
tiledBackground.setColorFilter(0xaacceeff, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
this.setBackgroundDrawable(tiledBackground);
```

I also have an animation thread where I'm drawing an image (successively adjusting its x coordinate so that it appears to move to the left). The background image is a transparent PNG and so some parts of it are transparent. It appears that the image I'm drawing from the thread appears *below* the background drawable on the `SurfaceView`. How can I have it appear on top of the background? I'm drawing the image like so:

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(missile, x, getHeight() - 95, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

`missile` and `paint` are initialized in the constructor of the thread to:

```
missile = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile));
paint = new Paint();
```

Comment: Probably won't work, but try adding super.doDraw(canvas) at the beginning of your onDraw method.

Comment: `doDraw` is not part of `Thread` and so I won't be able to call `super.doDraw()`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed up your doDraw with onDraw... I assumed it belonged to the extended Surfaceview. What class is doDraw in? Where do you call it from?

Comment: No worries! `doDraw` is in a class called `AnimationThread`, which extends `Thread`. I call it from my thread's `run()` method.

Comment: when you call doDraw, where do you get the canvas from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to doDraw should draw everything you want to be displayed, including the background.

```
// Add to initializer
tiledBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background));
tiledBackground.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
tiledBackground.setColorFilter(0xaacceeff, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);

private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    // Create a rectangle (just holds top/bottom/left/right info)
    Rect drawRect = new Rect(); 

    // Populate the rectangle that we just created with the drawing area of the canvas.
    canvas.getClipBounds(drawRect);

    // Make the height of the background drawing area equal to the height of the background bitmap
    drawRect.bottom = drawRect.top + tiledBackground.getBitmap().getHeight();

    // Set the drawing area for the background.
    tiledBackground.setBounds(drawRect);

    tiledBackground.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(missile, x, getHeight() - 95, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: This just gives me a black background-image unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I left off the setBounds call. See if the edited version works better for you.

Comment: This works *almost* perfectly. The only problem is that it wants to stretch the image vertically to fit the screen. Is there any way to stop it from doing that? Also could you add an explanation as to what the `Rect`, `clipBounds`, and `setBounds` does? Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to change setTileModeX to setTileModeXY so it tiles in both directions. I'll update the answer with that and also answer your other questions.

Comment: I don't want it to tile in the Y direction. The image is a drawing of a landscape and it is only tileable in the X direction. Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions!

Comment: In that case you'll want to edit the size of drawRect to the height of your bitmap. I'll make another edit.

Comment: A quick question. Why does the call to `getClipBounds` under canvas populate the rectangle? The sdk says that it retrieves the clip bounds, returning true if they are empty. Also, I tried setting the height of the `Rect` as you had described, but that didn't seem to work either. I think I must be missing something :p

Comment: You just want to set the .bottom of the rectangle to .top + the height of the bitmap. So if you know your bitmap is 100 pixels tall, change that line to "drawRect.bottom = drawRect.top + 100;" Also, I added the drawColor call back in at the beginning since your background will cover the entire canvas.

Comment: Thanks! I will need to tweak it and experiment a bit but that seems to do what I want. Thanks! So it looks like it scales it no matter what. The `Rect` seems to behave like clipping so I simply end up displaying different parts of the image. I'm going to play with it some more and if I don't figure it out, I'll just make another question. Thanks for your help!